# How to get a good "divisible by" symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

In addition to the "divides" relation, denoted *b | a*, there is also a "divisible by" relation expressing the converse (*a* is divisible by *b*), often designated with three vertical dots.

Up until now, I've settled with

```
\mathrel{\vdots}
```

[image: Example]

But there are two problems with the symbol:

- It is too high relative to the numbers
- It is also somewhat too long

A search with [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) and the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) doesn't reveal anything more suitable. How do I get a good looking "divisible by" symbol?

Comment: Is `$A \scalebox{0.75}{\vdots} B$` closer to what you want?

Comment: I agree with egreg that this is not an universal convention.  Is this a local convention (in some country)? or is this a new convention in some new branch of mathematics?  I am just curious.

Comment: @Sony: This is common in some Eastern Europe countries and Russia. On the other hand, the "|" relation is much less used in these countries.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've never seen that symbol. But here's how you can define it

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\divby}{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\baselineskip.65ex\lineskiplimit0pt\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}%
}
```

It's just an almost straightforward modification of `\vdots`.

[image]

In order that the symbol changes size when used in subscripts/superscripts, just enclosing the main part in `\text` will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\divby}{%
  \mathrel{\text{\vbox{\baselineskip.65ex\lineskiplimit0pt\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
a\divby b \qquad \sum_{k\divby n}a_k
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you update this answer to sync well with `\not` or `\centernot` in order to provide something like `\notdivby`? See [different ways to write a number is not divisible with another number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321448/5764).

Comment: @Werner `\not` or `\centernot` won't definitely work.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way to define a `\divby` symbol (it additionally requires [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) though):

```
\newcommand*{\divby}{\mathrel{\rotatebox{90}{$\hskip-1pt.{}.{}.$}}}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have another solution. :) You could also use `TikZ`. (This may be quite straightforward if you load the package in your preamble anyway.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\divby}{\ \tikz \foreach \y in {0ex, 0.65ex, 1.3ex} \fill (0,\y) circle (0.5pt);\ }

\begin{document}
$15\divby 3$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As the old saying goes: "When in doubt, use TikZ"

Comment: I would actually recommend against using TiKZ for typography when there is a vanilla LaTeX solution such as egreg's, because it will be much slower.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `stackengine` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\divby}{%
 \setstackgap{S}{0.45ex}%
 \mathrel{\Shortstack{{.} {.} {.}}}}
\begin{document}
$15\divby 3$
\end{document}
```