# vertical dotted line in column vector / amsmath matrix

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I would like to typeset the following set of equations:
[image]

... but with contiguous, vertical dotted lines in the column vectors, such that the top and bottom rows of the matrix and of the vectors are well aligned.

`\vdots` doesn't seem to be the right choice here, as I used it to produce the graphic above. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1 &     &     &     &\\
    c_2 & a_2 & b_2 &     &     &\\
        & c_3 & a_3 & b_3 &     &\\
        &     & c_4 & a_4 & b_4 &\\
        &     &     & c_5 & a_5 & b_5\\
        &     &     &     & c_6 & a_6
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    T_1\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    T_6
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    d_1\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    \vdots\\
    d_6
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If this isn't good style in terms of mathematical notation conventions (which I don't know), then, of course, I would write out the elements of the vectors. Clarification would be welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it like this, provided your main matrix has no unusually big objects (otherwise you can play with the first argument to `\dottedcolumn` that also accepts decimal numbers).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dottedcolumn}[3]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1$}
  \settowidth{\dimen2}{$#2$}
  \ifdim\dimen2>\dimen0 \dimen0=\dimen2 \fi
  \begin{pmatrix}\,
    \vcenter{
      \kern.6ex
      \vbox to \dimexpr#1\normalbaselineskip-1.2ex{
        \hbox{$#2$}
    \kern3pt
    \xleaders\vbox{\hbox to \dimen0{\hss.\hss}\vskip4pt}\vfill
    \kern1pt
    \hbox{$#3$}
  }\kern.6ex}\,
  \end{pmatrix}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1 &     &     &     &\\
    c_2 & a_2 & b_2 &     &     &\\
        & c_3 & a_3 & b_3 &     &\\
        &     & c_4 & a_4 & b_4 &\\
        &     &     & c_5 & a_5 & b_5\\
        &     &     &     & c_6 & a_6
  \end{pmatrix}
  \dottedcolumn{6}{T_1}{T_6}=\dottedcolumn{6}{d_1}{d_6}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Taking some code from [How to get a good "divisible by" symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32501/5764), you can create your own `\vdots` that has any number of predefined dots. Here I've defined `\sixvdots`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\sixvdots}{%
  \vbox{\baselineskip1ex\lineskiplimit0pt%
  \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1 &     &     &     &\\
    c_2 & a_2 & b_2 &     &     &\\
        & c_3 & a_3 & b_3 &     &\\
        &     & c_4 & a_4 & b_4 &\\
        &     &     & c_5 & a_5 & b_5\\
        &     &     &     & c_6 & a_6
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    T_1\\
    \sixvdots\\
    T_6
  \end{pmatrix}=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    d_1\\
    \sixvdots\\
    d_6
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Increasing the value of `\baselineskip` stretches out the dots.

Comment: Lesser artists borrow, great artists steal. ;-)

Comment: I will have to play with the `\baselineskip` value? Isn't there some automatic way to ensure exactly equal heights of all matrices + vectors?

Comment: nice, but i think a bit more space between the top line and the dots would be an improvement.  maybe the same amount of space that separates rows of the matrix would look best.

Comment: @AlexG: egreg seems to have delivered with a rough estimate, as expected... Since the context is not fully known, there is some user-intervention required to optimize the result. You want to avoid cluttering the interface with box measurements (to extract the height, say) if it is not really needed.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the package `nicematrix` which has functionalities dedicated to this problem.

Just with adding in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{renew-dots,renew-matrix,nullify-dots}
```

we obtain:
[image]

Here is the complete code.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \usepackage{nicematrix}
 \NiceMatrixOptions{renew-dots,renew-matrix,nullify-dots}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     a_1 & b_1 &     &     &     &\\
     c_2 & a_2 & b_2 &     &     &\\
         & c_3 & a_3 & b_3 &     &\\
         &     & c_4 & a_4 & b_4 &\\
         &     &     & c_5 & a_5 & b_5\\
         &     &     &     & c_6 & a_6
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     T_1\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     T_6
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
     d_1\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     \vdots\\
     d_6
   \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```