# How to type tensor multiplication with vertical dots?

Tags: symbols, tensor

I want to type this equation in LaTeX. How do I type those vertical dots symbol?

[image]

Comment: Use: `$\vdots$`.

Comment: `\vdots`, also helpful: [`\rvdots`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112212/16595)

Comment: `\multido{\i=0+1}{3}{\psdot(0,\i)}`?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32501/how-to-get-a-good-divisible-by-symbol

Comment: Use `\mathbin{\vdots}` to adjust the spacing around it.

Answer (score 4):

These are obviously binary operators, so they should carry the same spacing. That is, use whatever works and then wrap it in `\mathbin`. While the original picture showed the bottom dots resting on the baseline, I think it would be more correct to center the symbols on the math axis (where the `\cdot` is placed). Here is a simple possibility, that does not allow for size changes in scripts, but does respect global size changes like `\large`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\onedot{$\mathsurround0pt\ldotp$}
\def\cddot{% two dots stacked vertically
  \mathbin{\vcenter{\baselineskip.67ex
    \hbox{\onedot}\hbox{\onedot}}%
  }}%
\def\cdddot#1{% three dots 
  \mathbin{\vcenter{\baselineskip.67ex
    \hbox{\onedot}\hbox{\onedot}\hbox{\onedot}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
Test it:
\[
\mathbf{P} = \varepsilon_0 \left(\chi^{(1)}
    \cdot \mathbf{E} + \chi^{(2)}
    \cddot \mathbf{EE} + \chi^{(3)}
    \cdddot \mathbf{EEE} + \cdots \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Allowing for changes in scripts is a good deal harder, but could be done with the aid of some of the internals of the `mathdots` package.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the result that you're looking for:

```
\mathbf{P} = \epsilon_0 \left(\chi^{(1)} \cdot \mathbf{E}+\chi^{(2)} : \mathbf{EE}+\chi^{(3)}\vdots \mathbf{EEE}+ \cdots \right)
```

Result:

[image: equation]

Comment: You'd better use `\varepsilon` and wrap the `\vdots` with some spacing, like `\,`.

Comment: @m0nhawk not manual spacing, like `\,`, but one of the appropriates for math entities (`\mathbin`).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my first try with the `stackengine` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\tensorm}{%
% Uncomment below to adjust the gap between the dots
%\setstackgap{S}{0.6ex}%
\mathrel{\Shortstack{{.} {.} {.}}}}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{P} = \epsilon_0 \left(\chi^{(1)} \cdot \mathbf{E}+\chi^{(2)} : \mathbf{EE}+\chi^{(3)}\tensorm \mathbf{EEE}+ \cdots \right)$
\end{document}
```