# different ways to write a number is not divisible with another number

Tags: symbols

I would like to know how should I write that the number **a** is not divisible with the number **b**.

**b \not\mid a** and I have found there is also another method to write it **three vertical points cut by a line**. How can I reproduce **three vertical points cut by a line**?

thanks!

Comment: Could you show an image of the "three vertical points cut by a line"? Otherwise you could just try `\centernot{\vdots}` using the [`centernot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot).

Comment: Related (for a "three vertical dots" = "divisible by" symbol): [How to get a good “divisible by” symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32501/5764). Together with [How to negate a specific symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140996/5764) you should be able to produce a not-divisible-by symbol.